# How to show timer only for pages with time limit in SurveyJS?

Tags: surveyjs

When I run a SurveyJS survey with `showTimerPanel='top'`, the timer appears everywhere. Can I make it appear only on certain pages? Or at least the pages with time limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup the timer panel and start/stop timer on starting the survey and on current page change. Here is the code and [example in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/w4VqfTV0RLtVZlj9).

```
function setupTimerPanel(survey) {
    const showTimer = survey.currentPage.maxTimeToFinish;
    survey.showTimerPanel = showTimer ? "top" : "none";
    if(showTimer) {
        survey.startTimer();
    } else {
        survey.stopTimer();
    }
}
survey.onCurrentPageChanged.add((sender, options) => {
   setupTimerPanel(survey);
});
survey.onStarted.add((sender, options) => {
    setupTimerPanel(survey);
});
```

Please note, if you don't have a started page, then you need to call setupTimerPanel(survey); for your first page after creating the Survey model.

Thank you,
Andrew